# How to do not redirect specific file on nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I just set to redirect when visitors visit my website from http to https using below code.

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    ssl off;
    server_name seoartgallery.com www.seoartgallery.com ja.seoartgallery.com www.ja.seoartgallery.com;
    root /var/www/seoart;

    location =/example.txt {
    # do stuff
     }
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name  seoartgallery.com ja.seoartgallery.com www.seoartgallery.com www.ja.seoartgallery.com;
    root /var/www/seoart;
    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/seoartgallery.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/seoartgallery.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/seoartgallery.com/chain.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/live/seoartgallery.com/seoartgallery.com.dhparam;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    # Enable HSTS. This forces SSL on clients that respect it, most 
    # modern browsers. The includeSubDomains flag is optional.
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    # Set caches, protocols, and accepted ciphers. This config will 
    # merit an A+ SSL Labs score.
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

    error_log /var/log/nginx/seoart.error.log warn;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }


    # Allow Lets Encrypt Domain Validation Program
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        allow all;
    }


    # Add a slash at the end of request */wp-admin
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    # Deny files starting with a . (dot)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }


    location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

    # Add Rocket-Nginx configuration (of course !!)
    include common/yoast.conf;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


}
```

but i want to set only 1 file did not redirect to https. 
example ) http://example.com/example.txt

but i don't know how do i that

Please let me know how to i solve that

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below should work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /example.txt {
        # do stuff
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for answering.
but didnt work for me. exmaple.txt file still redirect to https://
what i put  in # do stuff filed?
please let me know how do i fix that.. Thank you

Comment: Try clearing browser history or using incognito mode.

Comment: Thanks for answering. but still not work. would you check my full code again?

Comment: You can try wrapping the return 301 in a 'location / {return 301 ...}'